# Inserting string at multiple position of another string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 vars and need to insert b into a after evry "}" and befor any css classes. How can I do this with jquery or javascript?

```
var a        = "p{font-size:20px}
                .tihais {font-weight:bold}";
var b        = "#afnay";
var position = after evry "}";
```

thx

Comment: thank you for your answer Andreas, but i looking to add a string, not to replace an existing

Comment: Just replace `}` with `"}" + b` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a        = "p{font-size:20px}
            .tihais {font-weight:bold}";
var b        = "}#afnay"; // This variable value is changed!
a= a.replace("}", b);
```

Comment: don't work with 3 line like :

Comment: p{font-size:20px}
.tihais {font-weight:bold}
.afrik{font-size:35px}

Comment: what do you mean?? Check the answer carefully!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 'p{font-size:20px}\n'+
'.tihais {font-weight:bold}';
var b = "}#afnay";    
a= a.replace(/}/g, b);
console.log(a)
```